# Viber (Desktop) isn't working in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: wayland

first of all, I had the issue of having a dark screen when I share my screen on a video call, after searching on the internet I could fix it by uncommenting the line

```
    WaylandEnable=false
```

in

```
/etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

But after this Viber stopped working! If I go back to the previous settings (#WaylandEnable=false) Viber works again. What can I do to make both work well, Viber and screen sharing, please?
Thank you in advance.